# Magento 1.9.3.2 - Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9

Error when try change the password of a customer from of the backend.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:1554
```

In the line 1554 of the Abstract.php file have this:

```
$backend        = $attribute->getBackend();
```

I see and i have the attribute rp_customer_id created correctly.

Any idea?.

Comment: how did you create the attribute rp_customer_id  and what are it's settings?

Comment: I have the same problem on a clean Magento install, it must be a Magento bug

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and noticed that I should have had an attribute called `password_created_at` in the eav_attribute table for entity customer.

This is created in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5-1.6.2.0.6.php`

Not sure why this didn't run, but I adjusted the core_resource table for customer_setup to 1.6.2.0.5 (version field) and cleared the cache so the setup reran.